# Using PL/SQL transactions with wizards in Oracle APEX 5.0

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions, oracle-apex, wizard

I'm trying to use a transaction process with a wizard in apex 5.0.
I want to register a new Student to the database, so in the first page of the
wizard I want to create a savepoint (s1) then insert the information of the 
student into the table "STUDENT", and in the second page I want to insert the info of the student's superior.
what I want to do is when the user click the Previous button, I want to rollback to savepoint s1 and undo the insert statement.
I tried to create a process but it seems that the rollback statement in the second page can't see the savepoint I declared in the first page.
so, does any one can help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Apex uses connection pooling. Unlike client-server environments like Oracle Forms, Apex is state-less. DB connections are extremely short and fleeting and are not tied to one apex session. The session in apex is something for apex itself. 
This means that transactional control is not as you'd think it is. A render of a page is a short DB connection / session and ends when the page has rendered. When submitting it'll be another session.

[Oracle Apex Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_ses.htm#HTMDB03008)

> **2.6.2 What Is a Session?**
>   A session is a logical construct that establishes persistence (or stateful behavior) across page views. Each
>   session is assigned a unique identifier. The Application Express
>   engine uses this identifier (or session ID) to store and retrieve an
>   application's working set of data (or session state) before and after
>   each page view.
>
> Because sessions are entirely independent of one another, any number
>   of sessions can exist in the database at the same time. A user can
>   also run multiple instances of an application simultaneously in
>   different browser programs.
>
> Sessions are logically and physically distinct from Oracle database
>   sessions used to service page requests. A user runs an application in
>   a single Oracle Application Express session from sign in to sign out
>   with a typical duration measured in minutes or hours. Each page
>   requested during that session results in the Application Express
>   engine creating or reusing an Oracle database session to access
>   database resources. Often these database sessions last just a fraction
>   of a second.

Can you still use savepoints? Yes. But not just anywhere. You could use it in one process. Can you set one in one page and then rollback from another? No. The technology just does not allow it. Even if it did, you'd have to deal with implicit commits, as outlined in @Cristian_I his answer.
For the same reason you can not use global temporary tables.

What CAN you use?
You could use apex collections. You can compare them to temporary tables, in that they will hold data in one apex session. 
Simply store your information in collections and then process the data in them once you get to the end.

The other things you can do is: well, you can just keep the data stored in your page items. Session state is in effect. You can still access the session state of the page's items on the final step. If for some reason you wish to move back a step and then "auto-clear" that page, all you need to do is to clear the cache for that page. This is more difficult if you wish to use a tabular form somewhere since you'd have to build it on a collection, but I'd recommend a repeatable step in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that Apex gives commit statements when you switch from one page to another.

A simple rollback or commit erases all savepoints. (You can find out more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm).) According to [a post by Dan McGhan](http://www.danielmcghan.us/2012/08/implicit-commits-in-apex.html) Apex gives implicit commits in the following situations:

1. On load, after a page finishes rendering
2. On submit, before branching to another page
3. On submit, if one or more validations fail, before re-rendering the
   page
4. After a PL/SQL process that contains one or more bind variables has
   completed
5. After a computation
6. When APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE is called
7. When APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE is called

Meybe you can simulate savepoints functionalty by using some temporary tables.

Comment: I created a temporary table called "std_temp", and I added a process that truncate the table when clicking the Previous button.  
when I tried:  
truncate table std_temp;  
it show the following error:  
ORA-06550: line 1, column 67: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":= was inserted before "TABLE" to continue.  
I tried to use execute immediate, but it didn't delete any rows from the table.

Comment: `Truncate table` is a DDL and if you want to use it in a pl/sql block you have to use it like this `begin execute immediate 'truncate table tablename'; end;` But what happens when you have 2 users doing the same thing? One will delete the date of the other. Maybe in this situation is better if you add the user who is doing the insert data(your first step) so when he press previous button you can `delete from std_temp where user=:APP_USER` and you don`t affect the data of second user.

Answer (score 0):

Since Apex is stateless and the results of each page request are always either fully committed or fully rolled back (i.e. no inter-page savepoints are possible), you need to make a choice between two strategies:

**Option 1:** allow the intermediate info to be committed to the table. One way to do this is to add a flag to the table, e.g. "status", which is set to "provisional" on the first page, and updated to "complete" on the second page. This may require changes to other parts of your application so they know how to deal with any abandoned records that are left in "provisional" status.

**Option 2:** save the intermediate results in an Apex Collection. This data is available for the scope of the user's Apex session and is not accessible to other sessions, so would be ideal for this scenario. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531

Comment: You can also (like I added too) just use page item's session state (option #3?). Nothing wrong with it in the context of a wizard-like setup and doesn't make you control data in tables or collections. Option 1 may be of use, but only if you'd want to allow them to continue with the data further down the line (because of the 'abandoned' records). The collection is an option too, but then again it depends on what exactly is in the entire wizard process. If it's just a few pages with single-record info, I'd still use page items.